# Sample Powershell script to call a .net webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, powershell

I have a .net webservice (WS) hosted on IIS7. This WS has a method to update a database. I have to call this method every two hours. I am thinking of writing a Powershell script to call the method and the Powershell script itself will be executed every two hours by NT scheduler. I have Googled for a sample powershell script, but couldn't find any. I am new to Powershell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a look at the help, and code examples, of the `New-WebServiceProxy` cmdlet. Type this in your console:

```
Get-Help New-WebServiceProxy -Online
```